# Silverlight 4 ContextMenu and ScaleTransform

Tags: silverlight, xaml, silverlight-4.0, contextmenu, silverlight-toolkit

The ContextMenu provided by the Silverlight 4 Toolkit worked great until I implemented a 
`<RenderTransform>` tag in my XAML in order to have the Silverlight app scale to fit the entire browser window (following [this](http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2008/08/26/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-33-how-to-scale-your-entire-app-and-its-elements-to-your-browsers-size.aspx) little tutorial)

When all worked great, before the tutorial, my XAML looked like:

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <!-- Rest of app here... -->
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now, my app looks like:

```
<UserControl>
    <Canvas>
        <Canvas.RenderTransform>
            <ScaleTransform [vars]></ScaleTransform>
        </Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <Grid>
            <!-- Rest of app here... -->
        </Grid>
    </Canvas>
</UserControl>
```

The scaling works perfectly, but now when I right click, the ContextMenu doesn't appear where it should (under the mouse). Instead, it appears at the same x-position as the mouse, but it shows up at the very top of the app. It's also very buggy, I have to keep clicking around to get it to go away, and I can't right click somewhere else to bring it up again, and it doesn't scale along with the rest of the app.

What might be causing this? Is there a correct way to go about fixing this, or should I just apply an offset to the menu to move it to the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to pass the cursor coordinates through the inverse of your scale transformation to convert the screen point to a point your application understands.

Comment: @Jesse - I haven't checked your code yet but if your scale transform is `x * 2` and `y * 3` I think you'll need to scale the mouse coordinates by `x / 2` and `y / 3`.